# How to connect chrome extension with mongolab

Tags: google-chrome-extension, mlab

I have a chrome extension i have made a sign up page and now i want to connect it with mongolab and store the data into the mongolab collection . Basically i want to make connection of a chrome extension with mongolab.

Comment: people giving negative votes give a reason first or answer if they know......

Comment: Your question lacks details; therefore, it's hard to answer and not useful to others. Quoting the downvote button: _"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"_ This is true so far. Take a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide to improve your questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got solution here on this web page : http://etoxin.net/blog/2013/07/09/mongodb-and-jquery-in-10-minutes/

Here they have used api of making a connection with mongolab using the api key of that collection created.

Comment: And it's not a good answer either. This is a so-called "link-only answer" - it points to an external resource and contains zero information in the answer itself. Community usually votes to delete such answers, unless you include at least some relevant information in the answer itself (how did it help you?) - since it will be worthless if the external link breaks.